# jQuery Input Mask Decimal point

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-inputmask

I am using the jQuery plugin found at https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask but I can't seem to be able to derive a pattern that corresponds to a integer & a decimal. For example,

I need the following to be valid:

```
      10
      150
      12.25
      0.45
```

At the moment I am doing:

```
$('#from_id').inputmask("9{0,5}.9{0,2}");
```

But this means that if the user does not specify what comes after the decimal point, the resulting output is:

For example, if the user only wants to input 12 (and he does not specify the decimal point) the output is

```
12___.__
```

(as the mask is waiting for the decimal point)

But if the user specifies the decimal point, for example 12.00, The output is fine like:

```
12.00
```

Could someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use the optional parmaneter `greedy` like,

```
$('#from_id').inputmask({'mask':"9{0,5}.9{0,2}", greedy: false});
```

Read [optional-masks-with-greedy-false](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask#optional-masks-with-greedy-false)

You can validate above mask. Or use your own logica to validate like,

```
$(function(){
    $('#id').on('keyup', function(e) {
        if (!this.value.match(/^\d{0,5}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/)) {
            $(this).addClass('error');// adding error class
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('error');// remove error class
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kgwe7by4/)

Or simply use [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) like,

```js
$(function() {
  $('#id').on('keyup', function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('error', !this.value.match(/^\d{0,5}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/));
  });
});
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="id" />
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, it is almost what i need. But the problem now is that if the user does not provide anything after the '.', i get something like: 12.  (if the user had just entered 12). Was that clear?

Comment: If the `.` at the end bothers you, you can make the whole part optional `"9{0,5}[.9{0,2}]"`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using multiple masks?

```
$('#from_id').inputmask({'mask':["9{0,5}.9{0,2}", "999"]});
```