# How to completely restrict decimal points from being entered in text input?

Tags: html, text, input

I have been searching through many HTML-related questions here and I am currently using the input tag pattern attribute to validate my inputs. This works by only allowing one or two numbers being input, and does not submit invalid data. However, I would prefer unwanted characters (decimal point and letters) to not be able to be put in the text box at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery Input Mask Decimal point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25526436/jquery-input-mask-decimal-point)

Comment: @ecorvo I can see how that would work, and I may end up using that. However, I was told that there was an HTML5 solution by someone else who no longer has whatever he had working. I'm trying to find that solution before I try jQuery.

Comment: you can define a number input field like this <input type="number"/>, it will filter out non numeric characters but will still allow you to put decimals..

Comment: @ecorvo that still allows decimals to be input, just not submitted - the same as the pattern attribute does with my current solution.

Comment: the only way to do this that I can think of is with regex, but for that I would just use a plugin, because the default HTML number input will let you put decimal since there is not an input type for integers only

Comment: You could use javascript and regular expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it for you https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/cfckvvzw/4/

updated fiddle to allow numbers in numlock to work too https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/cfckvvzw/5/

```
<input ID="FirstName1" class="test" onkeydown="return Fname(event);">
<script>
  function Fname(evt) {

    evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
    var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode : ((evt.which) ? evt.which : 0));


    //checks for invalid keystrokes (numbers only)
    if (charCode > 57 || charCode < 48) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: It is so hilarious to see you answer a question like this after the hard time you gave me for doing the same thing way back when.

Comment: WONDERFUL. Thank you! Just on a side note - obviously this isn't necessary, but is there any way to limit the number of characters to one or two in this function?

Comment: @ladyskynet What do you mean? a max number of two digits?

Comment: @TinyGiant and now you are complaining because I am being "more" helpful?! ....OK....

Comment: No not at all, that's great. It just made me laugh.