# How to restrict from entering a decimal value in input type number?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I want to have an input of type number `<input type="number">` and **I want to RESTRICT users from ENTERING DECIMAL VALUE**

> Note: I'm hiding the spin buttons of the input type text. [Know more here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_arrow_number.asp)

EDIT: **ANYTHING WILL WORK! EVEN JAVASCRIPT!**

---

I searched a lot but found nothing.

I did find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665914/how-to-completely-restrict-decimal-points-from-being-entered-in-text-input) but it basically blocks the use of any other key on the keypad except the number keys, so the basic problems occur such as the user cannot use *backspace* and cut the number entered, another problem is the user cannot use *tab* to change focus onto the next input.

---

**Thank You!**

Comment: "_I want to RESTRICT users from ENTERING DECIMAL VALUE_" plus this "_and NOT JavaScript_" - You cannot achieve this goal without JavaScript.

Comment: You can use the [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) attribute, but it may not do what you want without JavaScript

Comment: @RandyCasburn it is not preferred, but like I said, anything will work fine

Comment: @evolutionxbox - pattern attribute does not control what is typed by the end user - only applies to constraint API and what is accepted as a _valid_ input. You can also use the `step` attribute, but also doesn't _restrict_ input.

Comment: @RandyCasburn indeed, it is not an exact solution. Hence the comment not an answer.

Comment: You can use the step attribute - if it is 1 then decimals are not allowed and the system will complain (with an explanation) when the user tries to submit.

Comment: on `keyup` check the value, adjust it if necessary

Comment: @AHaworth no, I tried it but it doesn't really work

Comment: This cant be achieved with just HTML or CSS, you may have to do some JS and regEx magic.

Comment: @SalusSage yes, tell me, now I'm starving for an answer

Comment: I like this one personally https://stackoverflow.com/a/62351420/2622839
This post as more options, see if you like any.

Comment: Could you say what doesn't work about using step - is it because it doesn't check until the submit? If you want checking as the user types you may have to use JS.

Comment: @AHaworthyeah...I'm never actually submitting then form, it's for a real-time web application and I use the even listener of `input`. Please tell me a way to do it in JavaScript.

Comment: So do validation and show an error to the user when they enter in a decimal number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preventing user input can be done with JavaScript. I'd use the `input` event for catching values, as it's a unified interface, encompassing any input method you can think of `keyup`, `paste`, pointer events, touch events, etc...

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', e => {
  e.target.value = Math.round(e.target.value.replace(/\D/g,''))
});
```

```html
<input>
```

But you really **should not** do it! For at least the following reasons:

1. Forbidding user input is, by and large, perceived as disrespectful and drives users away. In short, it reduces any user engagement metric you can think of (funneling, sales, visits, sharing, etc...). Don't take my word for it. Do some A/B testing: present the same form with and without blocking user input and look at the results.
2. Form elements are just tools to help users give you data. But they are completely by-pass-able. If you give me a form I can send whatever I want using it, by simply opening the browser console. The validation must be done on server side. If you're using the value to do something on client side, sanitize the input value in the method, without changing user input.
3. A respectful way to inform users decimal values are not valid is by making the input `:invalid`, using [the `pattern` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) ( e.g: `pattern="[0-9]"`), styling accordingly (e.g: `:invalid { border-color: red }`), and displaying an appropriate message.
   Don't delete or block user input. They'll do it themselves if you tell them why the value is invalid.
4. When following web standards, your solution lasts. When you come up with hacks, there will always be the odd device in which your hack doesn't work. You don't know where things will be in 1-2 years from now, nevermind 5 or 10.
5. Last, but not least, have a closer look at [Constraint Validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Constraint_validation). You'll need to know and use it when creating quality UX and accessible forms.

Answer (score 1):

This is one option for creating an input element using javascript to limit the values that can be entered. I create an array of allowed keys, including all the digits, backspace, and tab as you specified. I added an event listener for the keydown event, and if the key pressed is not in the allowed group, I prevent the default action, or prevent the value from being entered.

I also added an event listener to the paste event, as you could right click paste and enter information that does not meet the criteria. Instead of trying to validate pasted values I disable pasting all together.

If you have any questions, please ask.

```js
const allowedKeys = [..."0123456789", "Backspace", "Tab"];
const myInput = document.querySelector("input");
myInput.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  const key = e.key;
  const allowed = allowedKeys.includes(key);
  if (!allowed) e.preventDefault();
});
myInput.addEventListener("paste", e => e.preventDefault());
```

```html
<input type="number">
```